# Poisson integral formula

Tags: mathematics, reference-request, complex-analysis

The term *Poisson integral formula* may refer to any of the related formulas for harmonic (or holomorphic) functions on a disk (or in a ball, half space, etc) in terms of their boundary values. This is the formula that contains the famous *Poisson kernel*. When and where did Poisson publish his integral formula? I have a paper which says it was published in 1820 (without reference) and hours of searching has revealed nothing more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that this is what you are asking for:

Mémoire sur la manière d'exprimer les fonctions par des séries de quantités périodiques, et sur l’usage de cette transformation dans la résolution de différents problèmes, *Journal de l'École polytechnique*, $18^e$ cahier, 11 (1820), p. 417–489.

[Here](https://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k4336744/f422.item) you can find the scan of the original paper (in French, of course).

---

EDIT

The so-called "*noyau de Poisson*" (Poisson kernel, clearly Poisson does not call it this way) appears at page 422.

Comment: Great! It is interesting that nothing is mentioned of the Laplace equation, Dirichlet problem etc but the Poisson kernel appears as a regularization of the Fourier series representing the delta measure.

Comment: ... Although Fourier will publish his ["Théorie Analytique de la Chaleur"](https://www.academie-sciences.fr/pdf/dossiers/Fourier/Fourier_pdf/Mem1828_p581_622.pdf) (where the Fourier series are introduced) only in 1828.

Comment: @JeanMarieBecker Fourier series appear for the first time in "[Mémoire sur la propagation de la Chaleur dans les corps solides](https://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k10535481/f12.item)", pp. 112-116, Nouveau Bulletin des Sciences par la Société Philomathique, published in March 1808 but presented at a session of the French Academy on the 21st of December 1807 at the presence of  Lagrange, Laplace, Monge and Lacroix

Comment: @user6530 Thank you very much for this important precision.